# Help proving a problem about an even (in the functional sense) marginal distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

Let $X$ have density function $f$ and let $Y = X$ with probability $0.5$ and $Y = -X$ with probability $0.5$. Show that $Y$ is symmetric about $0$, that is $f_Y(y) = f_Y(-y)$.

What I don't understand is how this is even possible considering that $Y=X$ and $Y=-X$ are two lines in the $x,y$ plane, the area of the joint distribution function over this domain should be relatively small ?

Comment: Self study ;) ? Can you start writing the density of $f_Y$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: I never asked for the answer first of all, I specifically said I am having trouble understanding (from a visual perspective) how this could exist

Comment: I see your point. The area is, in fact, zero. But, roughly speaking, it is not a "joint density per square unit" anyway. I think that [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91045/22228) is getting at the same issue as yours.

Comment: What is the probability (density) that $Y=5$.

Comment: Compute the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ in terms of that of $X$. You will be able to show it is differentiable; you can compute its derivative $f_Y$ in terms of $f$; and it will then be obvious that $f_Y$ is symmetric. (Using the CDF avoids any technical difficulties surrounding the singular nature of the *joint* distribution of $(X,Y)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given any real function $g(x)$ defined on all $\mathbb R$,
$h(x) = \displaystyle \frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}$ is an *even* function, that is,
$h(y) = h(-y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.